# How to solve VBA Insert into linked table error 3134?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a MS ACCESS front end connected to a Oracle SQL database via linked tables.

The issue: I try to insert some records with the statement below and always receive the 3134 error **syntax error in insert statement**

```
INSERT INTO DD_HR (USER_NAME, IS_DELETED, DATE_CREATED, DATE_MODIFIED, SNAPSHOT, HR_ID, COMPANY_CODE, CREATE_USER, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, DOCUMENT_NUMBER, PO_NUMBER, DUE_DATE, CURRENCY, ORIGINAL_AMOUNT, UNRESOLVED_AMOUNT, CREATED_DATE, CORRESPONDENCE, CORRESPONDENCE_DATE, PROCESSOR_DEADLINE_DATE, REASON_CODE, RESOLUTION_TYPE, STATUS, OWNER, PROCESSOR) VALUES ('username', 0, Now(), Now(), #05/10/2019#, 28588630, 'Org name', 'User name','Company',9999,'10397990','Subscription',#06/01/2019#,'USD',36558,36558,#04/25/2019#,'Yes',#04/25/2019#,#05/03/2019#,'Billing Issue','Rebill','Open','Billing WW','Billing WW')
```

Does anyone see from where the error might be? I tried to run the query in the database by just changing the Now() to sysdate and the dates from #mm/dd/yyyy# to to_date() just to be compliant with the Oracle SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the error, and fixed the issue: the CURRENCY field name is also a restricted word and needs to be enclosed within '[]'